# Forming pandas data frame from both keys and values of dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python `dict`:

```
{'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2', 'key3':'val3', 'key4':'val4'}
```

I want to convert this to data frame like this:

```
col1   col2
key1    val1
key2    val2
key3    val3
key4    val4
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass `dict.items()` in `Dataframe` constructor:

```
In [265]: data = {'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2', 'key3':'val3', 'key4':'val4'}

In [269]: df = pd.DataFrame(data.items(), columns=['col1', 'col2'])

In [270]: df
Out[270]: 
   col1  col2
0  key1  val1
1  key2  val2
2  key3  val3
3  key4  val4
```

OR, use [`from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
In [362]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['col2']).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'col1'})

In [363]: df
Out[363]: 
   col1  col2
0  key1  val1
1  key2  val2
2  key3  val3
3  key4  val4
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd
data={'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2', 'key3':'val3', 'key4':'val4'}
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(data,data.values())), columns =['col1', 'col2'])
print(df)
```